How to select an array element from a Riverpod NotifierProvider
I am trying to implement similar functionality to the basic example given in the Riverpod docs: https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider
Relevant code from docs with most comments removed, notifier:
@riverpod
class Todos extends _$Todos {
  @override
  List<Todo> build() {
    return [];
  }

  void addTodo(Todo todo) {
    state = [...state, todo];
  }

  void removeTodo(String todoId) {
    state = [
      for (final todo in state)
        if (todo.id != todoId) todo,
    ];
  }

  void toggle(String todoId) {
    state = [
      for (final todo in state)
        if (todo.id == todoId)
          todo.copyWith(completed: !todo.completed)
        else
          todo,
    ];
  }
}

Ui widget:
class TodoListView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TodoListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // rebuild the widget when the todo list changes
    List<Todo> todos = ref.watch(todosProvider);

    return ListView(
      children: [
        for (final todo in todos)
          CheckboxListTile(
            value: todo.completed,
            onChanged: (value) =>
                ref.read(todosProvider.notifier).toggle(todo.id),
            title: Text(todo.description),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Note the part in the code with the comment: // rebuild the widget when the todo list changes. The author seems to be aware that this will trigger the whole list to rebuild when you complete one task.
How do I avoid this? I was thinking that if I used a ListView with a builder I could maybe somehow use select, and only listen to one element from the array, but it seems that you can only listen to properties directly from the state, and since the state is an array that seems impossible? I would like an example how to design it in such a way to select only one element of the array to achieve rebuilding only one widget that changed.

I think you want a family provider so that you have separate providers for each element, not a shared provider where you have to select watching an element, especially since your add will move elements around.

there is actually an official example of todo list here
The main idea for the solution is that whenever todosProvider is changed, TodoListView will be rebuilded no matter what. what you want is to prevent the children from being rebuilded.
The way to do that is to cache each child using the const keyword.
the problem is that you cannot just add const before CheckboxListTile.
so instead, you need to create a new widget TodoItem for the todo child.
but you don't want to pass the todo through the constuctor because then the object will not be constant.
instead, you pass it through a provider.

@riverpod
Todo todoItem(TodoItemRef ref) => UnimplementedError();

class TodoItem extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TodoItem({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    
    final todo = ref.watch(todoItemProvider);

    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: todo.completed,
      onChanged: (value) =>
          ref.read(todosProvider.notifier).toggle(todo.id),
      title: Text(todo.description),
    );
  }
}

now you can call const TodoItem() and TodoItem will be rebuilded only when todoItemProvider is updated.
last thing left todo is to override todoItemProvider:
class TodoListView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TodoListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // rebuild the widget when the todo list changes
    List<Todo> todos = ref.watch(todosProvider);

    return ListView(
      children: [
        for (final todo in todos)
          ProviderScope(
            overrides: [
              todoItemProvider.overrideWithValue(todo),
            ],
            child: const TodoItem(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


This might work, but it still seems like bad design. I do not want the parent widget to be always rebuilt just because 1/20 (or similar) children changed. It also seems like a convoluted way to achieve something which seems like basic functionality.
